# Motivation vs. Purpose

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I felt there's a similarity in meaning and words could be used interchangeably when I tried to use the words in sentence, for example:

- My *motivation* to attend the course / meeting / study ..
- My *purpose* to attend the course / meeeting / study ..

In both of these examples, my reason to attend something is being stated.

From definitions, I got from Google there also seems to be some correspondence between them.

**Purpose:** the reason for which something is done or created or for which something exists.
*"the purpose of the meeting is to appoint a trustee"*
*synonyms:* ***motive***, **motivation**, grounds, cause, impetus, occasion, reason, point, basis, justification..

**Motivation:**
a reason or reasons for acting or behaving in a particular way.
*"escape can be a strong motivation for travel"*
*synonyms:* 
motive, motivating force, incentive, stimulus, stimulation, inspiration, impulse, inducement, incitement, spur, goad, provocation;

If not, how these are different? What about the word 'Objective'? Does it relate more to a purpose or motivation?

Answer (score 2):

They are definitely related words, and your sentence could probably work with either of them.

To put the three in order from broadest to most specific: motivation, purpose, objective.

**Motivation** often refers to an internal/emotional drive, or general goal

**Purpose** can refer to a general drive, but usually refers to something more concrete

**Objective** usually means a specific goal.

In an example: My motivation for joining running club is that I want to be healthier, my purpose is to increase my running stamina, and my objective is to complete a marathon.